# When creating a Blackberry Developer Certificate blackberry-keytool command not found is coming up in terminal

Tags: bash, blackberry, terminal, certificate, blackberry-webworks

May be an obvious error, but I am running the below & getting the error

```
-bash: blackberry-keytool: command not found
```

I am running this in terminal and cd to the correct folder. Any advice would be perfect!

```
blackberry-keytool -genkeypair -storepass password -dname 'cn=<company_name>'</company_name>
```

i am using the guidance over in the below and posted this there by have had no answer.

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/beta/testing_and_signing_setup.html#kba1383328834110

Thank you in advance.

Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Programs likes `blackberry-keytool` are all in the BB10 NDK directory. The first thing you should do to prepare for bash scripting is to run the development environment script inside where you installed the NDK. I'm on Mac OSX so I would execute:

```
/Applications/Momentics.app/bbndk-env_10_2_0_1155.sh
```

If that still doesn't work, you can find the program in your `/Applications/Momentics.app/host_10_2_0_15/darwin/x86/usr/bin` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your BlackBerry ID token (bbidtoken.csk) to the following directory:

```
Windows XP: %HOMEPATH%\Local Settings\Application Data\Research In Motion
Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows 8: %HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Research In Motion
Mac OS: ~/Library/Research In Motion
Ubuntu: ~/.rim
```

From the command line, navigate to the cordova-blackberry/bin/dependencies/bb-tools/bin subfolder of your BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK installation folder.
Run the blackberry-keytool command to create your developer certificate (author.p12 file).

blackberry-keytool -genkeypair -storepass  -dname "cn="

When you run this command, the author.p12 file is created in the same folder where you installed the bbidtoken.csk in Step 1.

Comment: Running that command resulted in "Error: Illegal option: cn="